# DateTime format error im xml Soap response from webservice

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, response

Error in XML document (45,65). ---> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

I'm getting an XML DateTime exception on my C# web app client when I call a web service that was auto-generated using Visual Studio web references. The error occurs at the web service client endpoint as the web reference proxy is formatting the XML response. Because of the type of error, I'm wondering if there is a .NET bug or incompatibility with converting certain Text formats to DateTimes formats. What's a good way to trace the cause of this error and to look at the XML response- I couldn't find a way in Visual Studio 2010 to examine the XML response from the Web Service. I appreciate the help I can get.

message:

at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExactMultiple(String s, String[] formats, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)
   at System.DateTime.ParseExact(String s, String[] formats, IFormatProvider provider, DateTimeStyles style)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.ToDate(String value)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderCONSULTA_CLIENTEBindingQSService.Read97_address(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderCONSULTA_CLIENTEBindingQSService.Read98_customerAddressList(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
   at

i´m using SoapUI for tests and work´s for show xml response, but in visualstudio 2010 theres an error.
 examplo for two dates response in xml using SoapUI >>>

1985-04-18T00:00:00

27/02/2009 16:07:02

Note: i consuming webservice from client.Just consuming..

Thank´s

Comment: Resolved.
 When the visual studio generates xsd references the webservice (java webservice) a datetime field was generated as a date and that generated the exception. Does anyone have any idea why this happens? this is a bug in visual studio? Thank you.